# Problem with socket connect in background

Tags: android, socket.io

I have some problem with socket IO. I start socket in service. When app in foreground or in stack socket get data from server, but when I close app, socket disconnect from server, respectively don't get data.

I need exactly socket IO, not FCM, GSM etc.

```
class AlarmService : Service() {

lateinit var socket: Socket

override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Timber.i("onCreate Service")
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Timber.i("OnStartCommand Service")
    try{
        var opts = IO.Options()
        opts.reconnection = true
        socket = IO.socket("URL")
    } catch (e: URISyntaxException){
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }

    if(!socket.connected()) {
        initSocket()
    }

    return START_STICKY
}

fun initSocket(){
    if(!socket.connected()) {
        socket.connect()
    }
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect)
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT,onReconnect)
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT,onConnectError)
    socket.on("alert",onAlert)
}

private var onConnect = Emitter.Listener {

    val body = JSONObject()
    body.put("token", utils.variable.token)
    socket.emit("registration", body)

    Timber.i("Socket in service connected : ${socket.connected()}")
}

private var onConnectError = Emitter.Listener {
    Timber.i("Socket in service error : ${it[0]}")
    GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
        Toast.makeText(currentActivity?.applicationContext, it[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

private var onReconnect = Emitter.Listener {
    Timber.i("Socket in service reconnect : ${it[0]}")
    GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
        Toast.makeText(currentActivity?.applicationContext, it[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

private var onAlert = Emitter.Listener {

    var json = it[0] as JSONObject
    Timber.i("Socket in service alert : $json")

    rxData.phoneNumber = json.optString("phone","")
    rxData.userName = json.optString("name","")
    rxData.alarmInfo = json.optString("info","")

    intent = Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
    intent.setClassName("com.ageone.alarm", "com.ageone.alarm.Application.AppActivity")
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){  
        user.isAuthorized = true
        router.layout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
        currentActivity?.startActivity(intent)
        coordinator.runFlowAuth()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Timber.i("onDestroy Service")
    }
}
```

Maybe you know solution for this problem?

Comment: You should make your service a foreground service.

Comment: I use 7.1 android, and  `startForegroundService` not supported on this version